# Двойное импортирование

Tags: python

***Как избежать такого вида импорта модуля?***:

```
from jetorm.jetorm import sqlite
```

Вот `__init__.py`:

```
from . import jetorm
__version__ = "2.3"
```

*Как мне его изменить так*, чтобы я мог **импортировать классы** так:

```
from jetorm import sqlite
```

Comment: Просто поместите все нужные вам переменные внутрь файла `jetorm/__init__.py` например вот так: `from .jetorm import *`. Или вообще переименуйте файл `jetorm/jetorm.py` в файл `jetorm/__init__.py` да и всё

Comment: Редактировать sys.path **не нужно**, такой способ не является переносимым между разными устройствами

Comment: понято! Мне тоже кажется, что так лучше будет, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\Your\Path\To\libs\Folder\Where\Stored\jetorm.py\file')
sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\somepath\to\libs\folder')

from jetorm import sqlite
```

Или так

```
import jetorm
db = jetorm.sqlite('db_name')
```

Comment: спасибо, конечно, но мне надо сделать так как я написал в вопросе)

Comment: Это первый вариант, необходимо добавить пути до библиотеки к вашему проекту
Просто сделат ькак в первом варианте не получится

Comment: хорошо, учту, но я думаю всё же есть способы изменить __init__.py так, чтобы можно было импортировать так, как я хочу

Comment: Думаю, что менять файлы библиотеки не очень безопасно

Comment: Или вы имеете ввиду собственный __ini__.py?

Comment: хех, это моя библиотека и я смотрю как бы это сделать)

Comment: собственный, да